# How do I make my code loop to where if the entered date is invalid, the user can try again?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“GL”)
    Dim xInput As Date, found As Range
    xInput = Application.InputBox(“Enter Friday date”, Type:=1)
    If IsDate(xInput) Then
        Set found = ws.Range(“F:F”).Find(xInput, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
         If found Is Nothing Then
             ‘Need code to have user try again
        Else
            found.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert (xlShiftDown)
        End If
    Else
        ‘Need code to have user try again
    End if
End sub
```

Right now I have code that just exits sub but I need help with code to where it will insert another InputBox to try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Loop` below, and also use the `FormatDateTime` to get in the `InputBox` a Date Format

```
Option Explicit

Sub NextFriday()

Dim FridayDate As Date

Do
    FridayDate = Application.InputBox("Enter Friday's Date :", "Date Selection", FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate), Type:=1)
    If Not IsDate(FridayDate) Then MsgBox "Error, not a Date format"
Loop Until IsDate(FridayDate)

End Sub
```